# Error while building android source code ( Lollipop -> master branch) on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit

Tags: android

I have been trying to build the android lollipop source code which I downloaded from the given URL i.e WWW.source.android.com
I followed all the procedures required to build the source code on my machine. 
Configuration of my PC : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit, i3-core processor,PC's RAM is 4GB , 1TB HDD

But I faced with some errors on the terminal which are as follows:

```
**clang++: error: unable to execute command: Killed
clang++: error: clang front end command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
clang version 3.6
Target: arm--linux-androideabi
Thread model: posix
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang++: note: diagnostic msg:
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/ARMDisassembler-d8183f.cpp
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/ARMDisassembler-d8183f.sh
clang++: note: diagnostic msg:

********************

make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libLLVMARMDisassembler_intermediates/ARMDisassembler.o] Error 254
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....**
```

help will be appreciated.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: try to remove libLLVMARMDisassembler_intermediates and re-run the code

Comment: I tried it and yes it solved. But later on my PC got hanged. I even tried commands like make -j2 and make -j1. But still the computer hangs after two and a half hours.

Comment: try using only make or else u need to check how mnay ram in ur system

Comment: sorry I didnt specify any configuration of my pc in the post.  my PC's RAM is 4GB , 1TB HDD

Comment: it would atleast require 8gb since i tried on 8gb and above system

Comment: Ok. But what if I use swap partition? Will it prevent from hanging? Because I haven't yet created any swap partition for the build.

Comment: Ok I will try using swap partition. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The issue is that probably your virtual memory size is below the requirements for Android build (16G).
I am using virtualbox and had the same issue.

I added memory in virtualbox ,yet I could not reach 16G becuase of my host resources, so I also added swap size:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/myswapfile bs=1024 count=16777216
sudo mkswap /myswapfile
sudo swapon /myswapfile
```

You can also check available memory (before and after doing all these additions) with:

```
free -k
```